# Custom Linklist class error

Tags: java

```
class Link {
    public Link next;    
    public String data; 
}

public class LinkedList {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String myArray[] = new String[2];
        myArray[0] = "John";
    myArray[1] = "Cooper";

        Link first = null;    
        Link last  = null;    

        while (myArray.hasNext()) {
            String word = myArray.next();

            Link e = new Link();    
            e.data = word;          

            //... Two cases must be handled differently
            if (first == null) {
                first = e;            
            } else {
                //... When we already have elements, we need to link to it.
                last.next = e;       
            }
            last = e;                
        }

        System.out.println("*** Print words in order of entry");
        for (Link e = first; e != null; e = e.next) {
            System.out.println(e.data);
        }

    }
}
```

> LinkedList.java:16: cannot find symbol symbol  : method hasNext()
>   location: class java.lang.String
>           while (myArray.hasNext()) {
>                            ^ LinkedList.java:17: cannot find symbol
>   symbol  : method next() location: class java.lang.String
>               String word = myArray.next();
>                                       ^ 2 errors

Few Questions...

1. Why did this error occur, i am trying to pass my Array of Strings. Still its not taking.
2. Can't we not declare Array of Strings like in JavaScript  way.

   String myArray[] = ["assa","asas"];
3. What does the hasNext() and the next Method do?

Comment: Arrays don't support the method `hasNext()` in Java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java arrays don't have `next` and `hasNext` methods on them.  You are probably thinking of iterators, which are typically used with container classes/interfaces such as `java.util.List`.

Note that you can initialize `String` arrays thus:

```
String[] myArray = { "foo", "bar" };
```

Comment: Now if i have to replace the array with some other data type... what should i do... i just need a series of words.

Comment: @theJava: Why don't you just write your loop as `for (int i = 0; i < myArray.size(); i++) { String word = myArray[i]; ... }`?

Comment: i am coming from this article and trying to understand it and replacing the SYstem.in with my words... http://leepoint.net/notes-java/data/collections/lists/simple-linked-list.html

Answer (score 1):

Here is a much more succinct way to iterate through the array

```
for(String word : myArray) {
//Keep the rest of the code the same(removing the String word = myArray.next(); line

}
```

That will iterate through the array, assigning the current value to word at each pass.